# In expresso-store is there a way to create a "Wishlist" or a saved cart that could be different from the checkout cart?

Tags: expresso-store

Looking to have the "add to wishlist" functionality in expresso-store.  This is basically just a saved shopping cart for the user.  The distinction is that it's not the cart that gets purchased in the checkout process.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in but you could use something like Shortlist or Solspace Favorites to allow users to create list of items for future.

Comment: I figured something like that.  Just hoping that there would be something a little more "plug and play."  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Shortlist is very to get setup and running and if you use the `{exp:store:product_form}` tag pair you can easily allow a user to add an entire list of items to the cart in a single click